# how to check if a typing value contains a list of map

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of map, so I want to check If the value I type contains any of the key value before adding.

here is my code:

```
for (var check in disciplineList) {
                        if (check.containsKey('degree') ||
                            !check.containsKey('degree')) {
                          if (check['degree'] != discipline.text) {
                            disciplineList.add({
                              'degree': discipline.text,
                              'date': currentDate
                            });
                            setState1(() {});
                            setState(() {});
                            discipline.clear();
                            currentDate = DateTime.now();
                            print(disciplineList);
                          } else {
                            openCustomDialog(
                                context: context,
                                body: '',
                                heading: 'Item Already Exists!');
                            print("Item Already Exists!");
                          }
                        }
                      }
```

Comment: `check.containsKey('degree') || !check.containsKey('degree')` should evaluate to *true* without concurrent modification of `check`.

Comment: so what are u suggesting @greybeard

Comment: @greybeard can you modify the code?

Comment: I probably could, given a specification or at least a description of state before&after - inputs&results. Disclaimer: I never coded using Dart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you have some List of Maps `listOfMaps` and you want to check if it contains

1- a specific key

you can do so like this:

```
bool doesItContainKey(var key)
{
   return listOfMaps.any((element) => element.keys.contains(key)); 
}
```

2- a specific value

you can do so like this:

```
bool doesItContainValue(var value)
{
   return listOfMaps.any((element) => element.values.contains(value)); 
}
```

3- a specific map:

you can do so like this:

```
bool doesItContainMap(var map)
{
   return listOfMaps.any((element) => element==map); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**.

Comment: You probably should prefer `element.containsKey(key)` instead of `element.keys.contains(key)` since `containsKey` should guarantee a runtime complexity of O(1) for a `Map` or O(log n) for a `SplayTreeMap`.  It's much less obvious what runtime complexity to expect from `keys.contains`.

Comment: Also, `doesItContainMap` checks the `Map` objects themselves for object identity.  If that's what you want, then it might as well just be `listOfMaps.contains(map)`.

Comment: @jamesdlin paste your idea answer

Comment: very cool but how to sort?